# Converting an FSK audio file coming from satellite to binary file

Tags: audio, binary-data

We have FSK modulated data coming from a satellite. We are using Kenwood radio TS2000 to receive the data. To record the data we are connecting the speaker output of radio to mic input of computer and recording the sound file. Now we need to make sense of this audio data as the actual data is purely some characters and numbers. We thought of converting the audio to binary data and further convert it into bytes. But we are stuck at this point.

If you can suggest some way (some software) of achieving the main task then it would be great.

EDIT:- Any of Windows or Ubuntu OS is fine, still preferably Ubuntu.

Comment: Better fitting than the original question ;) But some missing details. e.g. what OS must be supported?

Comment: No worries, that's what we check for if you missed something, and help you out. Please [edit] your question and include the facts, then let's remove the "obsoleted comments" ;)